# Placing text before every a href appearance?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently trying to place something like this `https://shortdomain.com/api?p=a-href-url-here.com` before every link on my website in a specific div.

```
$main = get_the_content_with_formatting();
$stripped = str_replace('<a href="http://example.net/', '<a href="https://shortdomain.com/api?p=http://example.net/', $main);
```

The method above works, but only when the link is that URL, and with any other it obviously will just return the standard URL.

Is there a way that I can prefix my desired link to each href using JavaScript, or PHP?

Here's the selector of the contents inside of `$main`

```
#the-post > div.post-inner > div.entry > p > strong > a
```

Comment: you could use a DOM parser in php

Comment: @IdontDownVote I thought about this, but it seems messy..

Comment: "Messy?" I'd submit that treating markup language like a plain text string is messy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever make the mistake of parsing HTML like text; it's not! Use a proper DOM parser to extract your values and then alter them.

```
<?php
$main = "<div><p>Here is some <a href='http://example.com/'>sample</a> text.</p></div>";
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($main, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $anchor) {
    $href = $anchor->getAttribute("href");
    if ($href) {
        $anchor->setAttribute("href", "https://shortdomain.com/api?p=" . urlencode($href));
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This will change every anchor in the document rather than just those beneath a `div`  with class `post-inner`

Comment: Actually I think he may only be providing part of the document content in `$main` so this code is ok.

Comment: It's hard to say from the question. I think you're probably right.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good task for PHP's built-in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) classes. Using xpath ensures that you only change anchors inside the div that you want.

```
$main = '<div class="post-inner"><div class="entry"><p><strong><a href="http://example.net">link</a></strong></p></div></div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($main, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$anchors = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "post-inner")]//a');
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    $a->setAttribute('href', 'https://shortdomain.com/api?p=' . $a->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div class="post-inner"><div class="entry"><p><strong>
    <a href="https://shortdomain.com/api?p=http://example.net">link</a>
</strong></p></div></div>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ubr5s)

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this client-side, it's pretty painless with javascript's `querySelectorAll`:

```js
let as = document.querySelectorAll('#the-post .post-inner .entry p strong a')
as.forEach(a => a.href ="https://shortdomain.com/api?p="+a.href)
```

```html
<a href="http://example.net/">Don't change</a>
<div id="the-post">
  <div class="post-inner">
    <div class="entry">
      <p>
      change these:
      <strong>
        <a href="http://example2.net/">some inside </a> <br />
         <a href="http://example3.net/">some other inside </a>
       </strong></p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute selector with jquery to match all desired elements and then use the method 'attr' to change the href attribute.

```
$("#the-post > div.post-inner > div.entry > p > strong > a[href=\"http://example.net/\"]")
    .attr("href", "https://shortdomain.com/api?p=http://example.net/");
```

I didn't really test it, but it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the dummy website then.

```js
$main = get_the_content_with_formatting();
$stripped = str_replace('href="', 'href="https://shortdomain.com/api?p=', $main);
```

Comment: What happens with `<a class="foo" href="...">`. Or, for that matter, just with 2 spaces between "a and "href".

Comment: then remove `<a`